# How do add Fragment so that it is not retained across Activity re-creation?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am adding and removing Views to/from my Activity dynamically. Each of these Views is assigned an id and acts as a container for a particular Fragment. I add a Fragment to each one of these Views with conditional logic as follows:

```
if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.someView) == null) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.someView, SomeFragment())
        .commit()
}
```

This conditional logic ensures that a given View only has a Fragment added to it once during the lifetime of the Activity.

This logic works fine except when the Activity is recreated (due to a configuration change for example). When the Activity is recreated, the Views are not automatically recreated but the Fragments appear to survive the recreation. (I see that the Fragments have survived the recreation because the `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(id:)` calls return a non-null Fragment.)

I find that if I re-add Views to my Activity in the `Activity.onCreate(savedInstanceState:)` method, then the retained Fragments re-attach fine to the Views and everything is fine. However, if I delay adding the Views to a later point in the Activity lifecycle, then the Fragments do not re-attach to the Views (and the Views show up as blank).

Ultimately, this leads to confusing logic in my `Activity.onCreate(savedInstanceState:)` method when `savedInstanceState` is non-null to work around this. Either I have to re-add Views as they were at the point when the Activity was destroyed (I would prefer to do this elsewhere in the Activity) or I have to call `FragmentTransaction.remove(fragment:)` to remove each Fragment which survived the recreation.

Is there a way to add a Fragment to an Activity such that the Fragment does not survive Activity recreation? I see in the deprecation notice for the [Fragment.setRetainInstance(retain:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) method that the guidance is: "Instead of retaining the Fragment itself, use a non-retained Fragment and keep retained state in a ViewModel attached to that Fragment." However, this guidance does not give any instruction on how to define a non-retained Fragment.

Comment: What version of Fragments are you using? [Fragment 1.3.1](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.1) specifically fixed an issue where Fragments wouldn't get re-attached if their container was added after `onCreate()` completed, which sounds like the exact issue you're trying to work around.

Comment: I have created a minimal Activity [here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/FragmentExperiments/blob/master/app1/src/main/java/com/tazkiyatech/app1/MainActivity.kt) which demonstrates the problem. If you run the app which contains this Activity on a device and then rotate the device, you will see that the Fragment does not re-attach itself to the View. You can also see this by running the `recreate_activity()` test method in [this](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/FragmentExperiments/blob/master/app1/src/androidTest/java/com/tazkiyatech/app1/MainActivityInstrumentedTest.kt) test class.

Comment: Note that AppCompat 1.2.0 depends on the years out of date Fragment 1.1.0. If you want to use a recent version of Fragments, you need to manually specify it.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Thank you for reaching out. I feel privileged  I am seeing this behaviour on the latest version of the `fragment-ktx` library (`1.3.3`). I have pushed an update to my sample app to include an explicit dependency on version `1.3.3` of the `fragment-ktx` library. See [here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/FragmentExperiments/blob/master/app1/build.gradle). Sadly, the app still exhibits the same problem.

Comment: Are you adding your fragment to a `FragmentContainerView`? As per the release notes, that is the only container that is possible to fix.

Comment: Ooh, `FragmentContainerView`. That's the first I've heard of it. Sounds good. I will try that tomorrow and get back you. Hopefully that fixes it. Thanks for your help 

Comment: @ianhanniballake: I just tried changing the `FrameLayout` in my simple activity ([here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/FragmentExperiments/blob/master/app1/src/main/java/com/tazkiyatech/app1/MainActivity.kt#L11)) to `FragmentContainerView` and it makes no difference. From the description of the [FragmentContainerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView) class, it seems it is for Fragments which can be defined in the XML layout of the Activity. I need to create my Views and Fragments dynamically so it seems it's not useful to my use case.

Comment: No, `FragmentContainerView` can be used just like any other container to programmatically add fragments as per [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-programmatic).

Comment: I have pushed an update to my sample app so that it nows adds the Fragment to a `FragmentContainerView` instead of a `FrameLayout`. You'll see that the retained Fragment still does not attach to the View on Activity re-creation if I add my View at a point later than the `Activity.onCreate(savedInstanceState:)` lifecycle method. I am questioning now whether this is a bug (which I should report) or by design (which I should code to workaround)? I am still interested to know whether it is possible to add Fragments such that they are not retained on Activity recreation and, if so, how.

Comment: I have created an issue in IssueTracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187105532) for the problem of Fragments not re-attaching to their Views when the Views are added to the view hierarchy at any point later than the `Activity.onCreate(savedInstanceState:)` or `Fragment.onViewCreated(view:savedInstanceState:)` lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of dimensions to this answer.

Firstly, I could not find any documentation or any methods in the [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager) or [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction) classes which offer a means of creating a non-retained Fragment. The documentation in the deprecated [Fragment.setRetainInstance(retain:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) method says to use a "non-retained Fragment" but I could not find anywhere that explains what this means.

Secondly, the workaround for this problem is to remove the retained Fragment in the containing Activity's `onCreate(savedInstanceState:)` method so that the problematic Fragment can be recreated and attached to its containing view in a later lifecycle method, as follows:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.some_activity)

    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.someView)?.let {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(it).commit()
    }
}
```